# Replacing All Punctuation with Spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, punctuation

I need to take a string, any string, and replace all punctuation (`',.!"`, etc.) with a ***space***.

So, if my string is originally

```
"sally sells seashells... but she's afraid of water"
```

the output needs to be

```
"sally sells seashells    but she s afraid of water"
```

We were told to convert s into a list, and use a for-loop including an if-block to do this.

```
s = "She sells seashells... but at home she's afraid of water."
alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def removePunctuation(s):
    slist = list(s)
    for i in slist:
        if i not in alph:
            slist.replace(i, ' ')
```

Comment: Basically, `str.replace()` function returns the string with the new characters replaced. You'll need to keep this in mind, and perhaps make a new string of the new characters

Comment: You should post a [mcve] as correctly-formatted text, **not** screenshots. @TerryA also they're trying to call it on a list...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, I didn't notice that. Technically the logic is still the same though

Comment: @jonrsharpe There you go. Sorry, first time on this website.

Comment: Note you should also include *what happens*, presumably an `AttributeError` traceback.